# Django: logging only for my project's apps

Tags: django, logging

By default I can enable logging in settings.py in the `LOGGING` configuration by creating a logger `""` which will catch all logs. But what if I only want to see logging from my project's apps as opposed to Django internals?

I can imagine explicitly getting a logger in each of my Django app modules and naming it by some convention, e.g. `logging.getLogger("myproject." + __file__)`.  Then I can create a logger called 'myproject' (in SETTINGS) which picks up all of these to output.  I'd prefer not to hardcode my project name, so I'd do some os.path logic on `___file___` to extract the full namespace up to the file at any arbitrary depth.

At this point, I stop and wonder is there an easier way?

Comment: Have you read through the logging docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#configuring-logging) ? There is a "myproject.custom" logger that appears similar to what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes I did. I didn't see anything that would simplify what I described, but if it does that would be a great answer.

Comment: I re-read your question after I posted my comment and realized it probably wouldn't offer any additional insight. To that, apologies.

Comment: Did you ever find a nice solution to this?

Comment: Honestly can't remember/tell at this point. I have upvoted these answers as they look pretty good.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understood your question, because the answer seems too simple.

Assuming you have defined in `LOGGING` a handler for your project's apps, for example like this:

```
'handlers': {
    'handler_for_my_apps': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': 'debug.log',
    },
```

and given your apps `app1`, `app2`, and so, you could have all the logs from those apps without any Django's internal logs by defining the loggers:

```
'loggers': {
    'app1': {
        'handlers': ['handler_for_my_apps'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
    },
    'app2': {
        'handlers': ['handler_for_my_apps'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
    },
```

There will be no Django logs in the same file, unless of course you defined a logger named `django` with a handler `handler_for_my_apps`.

In your apps you can get the logger using `logging.getLogger(__name__)` as recommended by the docs.

Unless I misunderstood your question...

Answer (score 22):

You could use a scheme like the following to create identical loggers for all of your local apps without having to manually add them all to the logging configuration.

First, split out your local apps:

```
LOCAL_APPS = [
    'myapp1',
    'myapp2',
    ...
]

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    'django. ...',
    ...
]

INSTALLED_APPS = LOCAL_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS
```

Next create the logger configuration for your local apps:

```
local_logger_conf = {
    'handlers': ['my_handler',],
    'level': 'DEBUG',
}
```

Finally, define your loggers as follows:

```
'loggers': { app: copy.deepcopy(local_logger_conf) for app in LOCAL_APPS }
```

Comment: this is a really good answer. It allows several applications to be created without having them all reside in a unique namespace that is specific to the project. However, it also allows you to grab DEBUG logging on all of them. Otherwise you end up with a cluttered log of all libraries OR you have to write a huge settings tree for each application, disrespecting DRY.

Comment: yes. This is fairly easy. +1 for your answer and +1 for django using python as configuration file

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for sharing, reading this post helped solve logging for my project. I'll share the solution I opted for, hoping it can help other people.
Define a list of Dictionaries:

```
LOCAL_APPS = [
   {'app_name': 'app1', 'level': 'INFO'},
   {'app_name': 'app2', 'level': 'DEBUG'},
   ]
```

Now create a function to modify settings' LOGGING:

```
def create_app_logger(app_name, level):
    app_handler = app_name + '_handler'
    LOGGING['handlers'][app_handler] = {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': f'../logs/{app_name}_logs.log',
        'formatter': 'custom',
    }
    LOGGING['loggers'][app_name] = {
        'handlers': ['console', app_handler],
        'level': level,
        'propagate': False,
    }
```

Finally loop through the list:

```
for dictionary in LOCAL_APPS:
    create_app_logger(dictionary['app_name'], dictionary['level'])
```

Since an app can be a world on it's own, this way you'll have a log file for each app, plus you have control over the logging level you want. It could be further personalized of course.

Cheers

Comment: This is better way of doing it.